# Snow leopard on a PC

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

Is it possible to run Mac OSX server on a x86 PC ... ? Any thoughts ? (our general manager wants to aquire half a dozen mini macs for some servers and he wants some testing with the mac osx server but i haven't got the mac machine to test drive the mac osx server for a couple months... any thoughts if on how i can do this on a PC ?

Comment: Any thoughts? Sure, it's against Apple's agreements to run it on non-Apple hardware, and you're probably going to get people giving negative reaction on a QandA site for sysadmins, or at a minimum warning you that you should pursue this on Google without too much assistance here since it's a big gray area for hardware/OS hackers. A Mac Mini can be picked up relatively inexpensively to test on, or talk to an Apple sales rep for your region to see if you can work out a deal with borrowing one for testing. We have done that with laptops.

Comment: eh... don't we all like a little weekend hacking :)

Comment: In addition you'll probably want a Mac for the desktop or a Macbook for administration purposes anyway if you're getting a significant number of Macs to use as servers. Get one now so you have a testbed and get acquainted with the platform.

Comment: @s.mihai-weekend hacking is one thing. Recommending something legally iffy with a group of professionals is definitely against best practices, at worst it can be a career issue if someone googles us for a job prospect and sees we have ethical issues in the business. Apple has usually been pretty flexible for us in trying to make a sale. I'd recommend contacting their sales team for an eval of some kind.

Comment: Doing it on a PC is iffy anyway; no proper hardware support, you may have performance or other issues that won't reflect real-world implementation. You'll want actual Mac hardware to test on. Apple doesn't break down your door (unless you stole a prototype iPhone, I guess) but they definitely chuckle when an update breaks hackintosh systems. Thus a trial unit or a used Mac (with proper support for the OS) off ebay. Look at MacTracker to see what Macs support what OS versions (free program)

Comment: Just to add that if you get a mac to do your test, if you install Mac OS X Server on it, you can then use virtualization software (parallels, vmware, virtualbox) to run others Mac OS X Server and emulate a larger number of computer

Comment: i've tried a few times and 2 times the deal didn't finalize and our sales rep got pretty angry with us (me) so... i like to get stuff done without the pressure from the sales rep (when will you have the results, paper work -lots-, all sort of financial reports and so on)

Comment: In that case...ebay a test unit. If he's serious about several systems for servers, an inexpensive used one shouldn't break budget, just look at MacTracker for support info first.

Comment: i don't think he's that serious (all the time and effort to move all our apps just for the space and power savings...) but... it dosen't hurt him putting us to work :))

Comment: If the boss isn't serious about migrating, then I'd look at test units off ebay or a commitment to purchase before treating it like a hobby. Treating servers as hobbies isn't generally good for business and bodes not too well for things like proper backups and administration of the servers (I mean...half a dozen Mac Mini's on a lark, and then deciding not to use it after all? No wonder your rep got irritated, unless there's more to this...)

Comment: If this is all a whim that won't come to fruition, your best bet is googling for info on OS X on PC's. The hardware support is iffy, updates break them, but there's groups that do this for fun (illegally). For a business that actually has cash flow riding on server reliability and support, I'd never do it.

Answer (score 2):

Many information can be found on google.
**Running Mac OS X on a non Apple hardware doesn't comply with Mac OS X license agreement.**
This is really not the right place to ask for this... there is dedicated website for this.

Comment: yea... i was just looking for some helpful thoughts and links before the thread got deleted by the adimins

Comment: http://wiki.osx86project.org/ is the best place to start.

Comment: the magic keyword is 'hackintosh' but if you're serious about possibly buying 6, just buy a single one and test it -- as there was a hardware refresh *yesterday*, nothing but a new purchase is going to be a valid test for performance.  If it doesn't work, for your needs you repurpose it, sell it or make sure you're within the return policy.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X is only supported on Apple hardware. It is possible to install it on non Apple hardware have a look [**here**](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It may be easier (and safer) to just wait for the server to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported, but that isn't to say there aren't plenty of guides detailing how it can be done. Here's the one I've used previously (edit: not in a work environment) which details the process quite thoroughly.

http://lifehacker.com/5351485/how-to-build-a-hackintosh-with-snow-leopard-start-to-finish

Biggest problem thou is always the hardware support; Apple put a lot of work into making OS X work with *their* hardware, but the guide details some parts that are known to work fine.

Comment: i've found a couple VMware machines that do the trick but not with the server version of their software

Comment: Your link say : "Update: This guide has been superceded by a much easier method: Install Snow Leopard on Your Hackintosh PC, No Hacking Required.". Why don't give the right link directly ?

Comment: Because the guide I linked was the one I can verify works, however OP can make up their own mind as to which to use.

Answer (score 0):

As **[radius](https://serverfault.com/questions/152580/snow-leopard-on-a-pc/152584#152584)** said, it's a violation of Apple's terms. It's also quite a hack and wouldn't be an accurate way to evaluate the feasibility of the proper setup.